# Angular testing component with mocked structural directive fails

Tags: angular, angular-directive, angular-test

I am trying to mock structural directive in a component test but Im getting error.

Following test is failing with a message:

> Property binding appSome not used by any directive on an embedded template. Make sure that the property name is spelled correctly and all directives are listed in the "@NgModule.declarations". ("[ERROR ->]TEST

I am mocking structural directive `SomeDirective` with `SomeMockDirective` defined within app.component.spec.ts. **Test is failing**.

If I switch declarations so that it contains `SomeDirective` instead - **the test passes**.

*I im wondering why I can not make it working with mocked version.*

Template:

```html
<h1 *appSome="true">TEST</h1>
```

Directive (kind of production :) ):

```js
@Directive({
  selector: '[appSome]'
})
export class SomeDirective implements OnDestroy {
  show: boolean;
  ...
}
```

Test:

```js
import { TestBed, async } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { Directive, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appSome]'
})
export class SomeMockDirective {}

describe('AppComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [AppComponent, SomeMockDirective], // test is failing, switch the directive to SomeDirective and it passes
      schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  it('should create the app', () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    expect(app).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Reproduction repo:
https://github.com/felikf/angular-test-directive

```
git clone https://github.com/felikf/angular-test-directive.git 
npm i
ng test
```

My question is, why the mocked version does not work, even if the mocked version is provided in `providers: []` and the directive has the same selector.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The mocked version doesn't work because you haven't defined `appSome` input property:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appSome]'
})
export class SomeMockDirective {
  @Input() appSome;  <================= add this
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. Can you point me to the Angular documentation where is this mentioned?

Comment: You can start with documentation https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#translation Where you can notice that your structural directive is translated to `<ng-template [appSome]="true"`. Then you should be aware that in Angular we should have dedicated input property for any property binding.